# how to generate a set of continuous one in verilog

Tags: verilog

I hope to generate a set of continuous one in verilog like

```
3 -> 'b111
4 -> 'b1111
5 -> 'b11111
```

I hope I can use `{num{1'b1}}`, but I found that the value must be constant.
Is there any way in verilog that I can generate the a set of continuous one value?

Answer (score 2):

Using system verilog you can use the `'1` syntax which automatically sizes correctly against the left hand side.

Also the above function `2^N - 1` in Dodon Victors answer is just `-1` in signed notation. I have shown the usage of both below.

Some simulators may not work correctly with widths greater than 32, although I believe all modern simulators have fixed this issue.

Example below on [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3r2):

```
module dut;

  logic [65:0] test1;
  logic [65:0] test2;

  initial begin
    #1ps;
    test1 = '1;
    test2 = -1;

    #1ps;
    $displayb(test1);
    $displayb(test2);
  end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
# 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
# 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 0):

N continuous 1 is just 2^N - 1, so you can use:

```
module test;
  initial begin
    $display("%b", ('b1 << 1) - 'b1);
    $display("%b", ('b1 << 2) - 'b1);
    $display("%b", ('b1 << 3) - 'b1);
    $display("%b", ('b1 << 4) - 'b1);
    $display("%b", ('b1 << 5) - 'b1);
  end
endmodule
```

and the output:

```
01
011
0111
01111
011111
```

You can use a function to generate like this:

```
function [31:0] gen1;
    input [5:0] n;
begin
    gen1 = ('b1 << n) - 1;
end
endfunction
```

then just call it using `gen1(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `~('1 << n)`

Test module:

```
module test;
  logic [7:0] a1=~('1 << 1) ;
  logic [7:0] a2=~('1 << 2) ;
  logic [7:0] a3=~('1 << 3) ;
  initial begin

    $display("%b", a1 );
    $display("%b", a2 );
    $display("%b", a3 );
  end
endmodule
```