# SystemVerilog: Parameter used in concatenation gives error with irun

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, cadence

Cadence irun gives error for below code, where fifo_depth_base2 is parameter as below:

> ncvlog: *E,NONOWD (buff_mgr.v,17|46): Illegal use of a constant without an explicit width specification [4.1.14(IEEE)].

I can understand this error, but my question is how would I otherwise assign it for parameterized design.

```
// rd pointer and read logic
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if(rst) rd_ptr <= 0;
else begin  
    case({flush, rd})
        2'b10, 2'b11: rd_ptr <= {fifo_depth_base2{'b0}}; // error here
        ...
 endcase
end
end
```

Comment: I think in SystemVerilog, when using a construct like this `fifo_depth_base2{'b0}`, fifo_depth_base2 should be a constant. You can probably use a for loop to make it parameterized, or just `rd_ptr <= '0`.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239366/how-to-generate-a-set-of-continuous-one-in-verilog

Comment: @Ari, `fifo_depth_base2` is a parameter, so it is already a constant.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a 1 before `'b0`. The simulator doesn't know the bit size of `'b0` because it is not specified.

`{fifo_depth_base2{'b0}};` should be `{fifo_depth_base2{ 1'b0}};`

With SystemVerilog you can use: `rd_ptr <= '0;`, where `'0` means fill zeros